# Redesign using State Design Pattern -doubts

Tags: design-patterns, class-design

I want to redesign a code using state design pattern. The states belong to specific objects.

**Example:**

Class A can have three states: st1, st2, st3.

Similarly, another class, B, can have 2 states: st4, st5.

There is a case where a class C has one state: st1 and st4 and st5.

Basically these states should be interchangeable in case of complex objects.

Also, these classes A, B, and C contain data specific to them which will be used by the states.

**My question is**: How should the state machine be designed? Should there be individual SM for every class? Can all states have a common base interface?

Please help me out; you can ask me more questions if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question how should the state
>   machine be designed ,should there be
>   individual SM for every class ?

If I understand your description, the answer is "yes", each object would require its own state machine.

> Can all states have a common base
>   interface ?

A common interface implies common API with multiple implementations.  What common methods will each state have, and how do the implementations differ by state?

You may not need a class for each state if there's no different behavior.  You may just have a State class and a FSM that manages a collection of States and the rules that govern transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I think this approach looks good for initial start , Once all the functionalities of existing code are discussed there could be more refinements to this

Answer (score 0):

In my humble experience, the state design pattern is somehow hard to use, as it tends to generate a lot of boilerplate code. I usually prefer the standard function pointer approach of the problem. It is an easier way if your objects / states are not too big / too complex.

my2c

Comment: I think you are right if the objects are small and the states are not too many , but I think in my case I would like to have a extensible design . Since using function pointers seem to be a immediate solution Plus I feel it requires a bit extra effort in maintenance

Comment: @wthomas: the devil is in the details :) Good luck with your code !